# At net zero points

Tags: phrase-usage

> Thumbs-up from me, although **at net zero points**, it looks like someone
>   didn’t appreciate the humor.

I can understand the meaning of "at net zero points" alone, however, in this sentence I can't figure out what the writer wanted to say exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming this is from SE, reddit, or a similar site where users upvote and downvote content. The "net points" are the number of upvotes minus the number of downvotes. The author of the quote is pointing out that even though they themselves upvoted the post, the post has a net point total of zero, meaning someone else must have downvoted. Evidently the downvoter(s) found the post objectionable in some way, perhaps not finding it funny.